# Java EE 7 + GlassFish 4 - Run bean on startup

Tags: cdi, startup, glassfish-4, java-ee-7

Using CDI is there a way to cause a bean to be instantiated when the application server starts up?

I would like to be able to do something like:-

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class StartupBean {
...
}
```

Unfortunately, although the `@Singleton` annotation exists in the `javax.inject.*` package the `@Startup` annotation doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use both of those from the `javax.ejb.*` package. EJBs support CDI and you can kick off anything you want.

Comment: Note that a CDI \@ApplicationScoped class is not single-threaded like en EJB marked with \@Startup & \@Singleton.